# im making a discord bot using discord.py but i keep getting "client has no attribute command" error

Tags: python, discord.py

so im currently working on a discord bot but im trying to make a command to allow me (the creator) to change its status using a command but it keeps giving me this error. heres my code so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot    
import RavensTools
import random as r

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents, command_prefix = '.',activity = discord.Game(name="Heres a goofy random number: {}".format(r.randint(1,1000))))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
prefix = '.'
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith(prefix+'hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    if message.content.startswith(prefix+'add'):
        if message.author.name == 'RavenVR':
            f = open(r'goody.txt', 'r+')
            f.seek(0)
            a = int(RavensTools.LTS(f.readlines()))
            f.truncate()
            a += 5
            f.seek(0)
            f.writelines(str(a))
            f.seek(0)
            await message.channel.send("current number is: {}".format(RavensTools.LTS(f.readlines())))
            f.close()
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You do not have permission to use this command!")
# ------------------------ this is the line of code I keep getting errors on -----------------
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def p(context, text: str):
    """Clear a specified number of messages in the chat"""
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=text))
            
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Thank you for your time and help.
Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `discord.Client`, use the `Bot` class you imported. `Client` doesn't have the `command` attribute (hence the error) but `Bot` does.

```py
client = Bot(
    intents=intents,
    command_prefix='.',
    activity = discord.Game(name="Heres a goofy random number: {}".format(r.randint(1,1000))
)
```

See the commands reference [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html).